# form with ModelMultipleChoiceField give only 'object name' even with __unicode__ and __str__

Tags: python, django

Here is my code :

```
from django.db import models

class Stock(models.Model):
    name =  models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=20)
    code = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=20)

    def ___str__(self):
        return self.name

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Here is my form :

```
class SubEventForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100,label="Name")
    note = forms.CharField(max_length=200, label="Global Note")
    stock = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Stock.objects.all(),label="Stock")
```

Here is the render :

[image]

i've put `__str__` and `__unicode__` and the admin vision is correct :

[image]

So any idea why it's not working ?

Regards and thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **str** method declaration in your code has a typo (3x underscore instead of 2x)

```
"def ___str__(self):"
```